# Is there a manual/list of special Gtk CSS properties?

Tags: gtk3

I'm trying to redesign some Gtk3 widgets in my application (like scrollbars or paned) but was unable to set borders and other properties for paned specifically.

I then found some CSS data in /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-3.0/gtk.gresource, which use special Gtk properties like "-GtkPaned-handle-size", "-GtkCheckButton-indicator-size" etc.

These were not listed in DevHelp, nor was I able to find it on developer.gnome.org. I think such properties could be exactly what I need. Is there a listing of them with or without a possible description?

EDIT: I wouldn't mind too much searching for them in source code if it is the only way to find names of the properties. Could anyone point me to the right place where to look, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are taken from the names of "style properties" - you can find them in Devhelp, in the sections below the regular properties.

The corresponding CSS property names are built like `-ClassName-property-name`; so `-GtkPaned-handle-size` would be the `handle-size` property of `GtkPaned`.

Note that style properties are going to be removed in GTK 4, and everything will be customizable by regular CSS properties.

Comment: What about here? https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/css-properties.html

Comment: They aren't visible in the new documentation, presumably because GTK 4 and later no longer use them.

Comment: so they aren't at https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/css-properties.html ?

Comment: No, those are the regular CSS properties. Style properties like `-GtkPaned-handle-size` don't exist in GTK 4.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a listing of them with or without a possible description?

- Run your program
- open the inspector (`Ctrl` + `shift` + `i`)

  - [How to enable GTK inspector](https://askubuntu.com/a/748152)
- select the widget you're interested in.
- From the combo-box, select `CSS Nodes`

[image]

Comment: How do you enable GTK3 inspector?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/748152